# How to pass variable from outer loop to the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to use the `x` variable in the "$("#brand").html" section at the bottom

```
for (x = 0; x < productList.length; x++){
    $("#drug" + x).html("<h2>"+ productList[x].brandName + "</h2>");

     $("#drug" + x).click(function(){
        $.getJSON("pharmaceutical.json", function() {
             alert(productList, x);
            drugData = data.pharmaceutical.products;
            $("#brand").html(drugData[x].brandName);
        });
     });
}
```

I keep getting this error in the console

**Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined**

I believe it's because x isn't in the same scope.

Any Help would be awesome!!!

Comment: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](//stackoverflow.com/q/750486)

Comment: Where you defined "data", Are you getting correct values in alert(productList,x) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a closure & refer to the variable.
Hope this snippet will be useful(not tested).

```
for (x = 0; x < productList.length; x++) {
  $("#drug" + x).html("<h2>" + productList[x].brandName + "</h2>");
  // creating a closure
  (function(i) {
    $("#drug" + i).click(function() {
      $.getJSON("pharmaceutical.json", function() {
        alert(productList, i);
        drugData = data.pharmaceutical.products;
        $("#brand").html("hello" + drugData[i].brandName);
      });
    });
  }(x))

}
```

Comment: It still doesn't carry the variable

Comment: can you please check the console & share the error?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Thanks so much I figured it out by looking at your solution. I had to change i to x and also define the variable for the getJson statement!

Comment: I guess you want to get the response as `data`. Probably like this `$.getJSON("pharmaceutical.json", function(data) { ../rest of the code`

Comment: yea that's turned out to be my problem. Looked at this code for 25 minutes before realizing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change to this:

```js
for (x = 0; x < productList.length; x++) {
  $("#drug" + x).html("<h2>" + productList[x].brandName + "</h2>");
}
$("[id^='drug']").click(function() { //<----gives you all the nodes with id="drug1"..
  var x = this.id.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]; // you can get it this way
  $.getJSON("pharmaceutical.json", function(data) { // <----get the response
    alert(productList, x);
    drugData = data.pharmaceutical.products; // find the specific one
    $("#brand").html(drugData[x].brandName); // place it in the DOM
  });
});
```